# Hotelling t at 0.95 interval

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, hotelling-t2

Suppose I want to test the hypothesis that the lengths of head size for first borns and seconds borns are $x = (182, 182)$ by using the Hotelling-T test.

So given our data:

```
"headsize" <- 
matrix(c(191, 195, 181, 183, 176, 208, 189, 197, 188, 192, 179, 183, 174, 190, 188, 163, 195, 186, 181, 175, 192, 174,
    176, 197, 190, 155, 149, 148, 153, 144, 157, 150, 159, 152, 150, 158, 147, 150, 159, 151, 137, 155, 153,
    145, 140, 154, 143, 139, 167, 163, 179, 201, 185, 188, 171, 192, 190, 189, 197, 187, 186, 174, 185, 195,
    187, 161, 183, 173, 182, 165, 185, 178, 176, 200, 187, 145, 152, 149, 149, 142, 152, 149, 152, 159, 151,
    148, 147, 152, 157, 158, 130, 158, 148, 146, 137, 152, 147, 143, 158, 150)
, nrow = 25, ncol = 4
,  dimnames = list(character(0)
, c("head1", "breadth1", "head2", "breadth2")
)
)
```

I implemented the following:

```
testd <- headsize

n = nrow(testd)
m <- c(182, 182)
p = length(m)
mu <- apply(testd, 2, mean)
muB <- mu - m
ss <- cov(testd)
invss <- solve(ss)
Ht <- n%*%t(mu-m)%*%invss%*%(mu-m)

tt = (n-p)/(n*p-p)*Ht
```

```
##tt
1.925323
```

The notes I am reading says there is little evidence that the mean of head lengths are not equal to 182 by providing
$$F_{2, 23}T_{0.95}=3.422$$

How was the final part calculated?

Additional content; would the following suggest that the circle contains all points, these points are contained within the Hotelling 0.95th interval?

Example:

```
#example data
smp=np.array([191, 195, 181, 183, 176, 208, 189, 197, 188, 192, 179, 183, 174, 190, 188, 163, 195, 186, 181, 175, 192, 174,
    176, 197, 190, 155, 149, 148, 153, 144, 157, 150, 159, 152, 150, 158, 147, 150, 159, 151, 137, 155, 153,
    145, 140, 154, 143, 139, 167, 163, 179, 201, 185, 188, 171, 192, 190, 189, 197, 187, 186, 174, 185, 195,
    187, 161, 183, 173, 182, 165, 185, 178, 176, 200, 187, 145, 152, 149, 149, 142, 152, 149, 152, 159, 151,
    148, 147, 152, 157, 158, 130, 158, 148, 146, 137, 152, 147, 143, 158, 150])
testDF = pd.DataFrame(np.split(smp, 4)).T
gender = np.tile([0,1], 13)[:-1]
np.random.shuffle(gender)
testDF['gender'] = gender
testDF = testDF.rename(columns={0:'head1', 1:'breadth', 2:'head2', 3:'breadth2', 'gender':'gender'})


#calculation
from sklearn import decomposition
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy, random

theta = np.concatenate((np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 50), np.linspace(np.pi, -np.pi, 50)))
circle = np.array((np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)))
sigma = np.cov(np.array((DF.iloc[:, 0].values, DF.iloc[:, 2].values)))
ed = np.sqrt(f.ppf(0.95, 2, 23))
ell = np.transpose(circle).dot(np.linalg.cholesky(sigma) * ed)
a, b = np.max(ell[: ,0]), np.max(ell[: ,1])

cnt_c = np.mean(DF.iloc[:, 0].values)
cnt_cc = np.mean(DF.iloc[:, 2].values)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
ellipse = Ellipse((cnt_c, cnt_cc),
        width=a*2,
        height=b*2,
                 facecolor = 'none',
                 edgecolor = 'k')

ax.add_patch(ellipse)

ax.scatter(DF.iloc[:, 0].values, DF.iloc[:, 2].values)
plt.grid(color = 'lightgray', linestyle = '--')
plt.show()
```

#plot
[image]

Comment: If you're asking "how would I find that value to use in my code?", try `qf(.95,2,23)`. The use of "$T$" in that notation seems unconventional, I'd be curious to see how they defined the meaning of their notation; I'd normally have written $F^{-1}_{2,23}(0.95) = 3.422$ (or perhaps, in some contexts, $F_{2,23;0.95} = 3.422$)

Comment: If, instead, you're asking "how are F critical values actually computed *inside* the `qf` R function?" or "how are tables of critical F values obtained?" ... that's a rather different question. It would be good to clarify what you mean

Comment: @Glen_b Brilliant! thank you for sharing. Yes, the $T$ notation had me uncertain. On an additional question, If I create a confidence region of $F^{-1}_{p, n-p}(0.95)$ for the data above, would this then suggest that all points within the region show evidence that mean head lengths are equal to 182cm?

Comment: No. If you construct a joint confidence region that includes the point $(182,182)$ (for units of cm) that does not constitute evidence that $\boldsymbol{\mu} = (182,182)^\top$, only a lack of evidence that it *differs* from that value -- not being able to rule it out is not the same as asserting it to be the case. Note that there's an infinite collection of other value-pairs that are included in the confidence region; the population mean-vector cannot actually be equal to all of them!

Comment: If that `qf` thing actually answered your original question, I could post it as an answer, but I am still not clear that it was responsive to what you sought.

Comment: @Glen_b That is what I had in mind. Sure you can go ahead and post as an answer. Essentially, I wanted to know how it was derived because I was going to test whether a confidence region plot based on the value for `qf` could be used.

Comment: Oh, did you want a derivation that the statistic you calculate in `tt` i.e. $\frac{(n-p)}{p(n-1)} t^2$ has an $F$-distribution under $H_0$? i.e. a proof of the results of [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling%27s_T-squared_distribution#Hotelling_t-squared_statistic) of the Wikipedia page on the $T^2$ test?

Comment: Or was the evaluation of the quantile to compare with sufficient?

Comment: @Glen_b I want to discover all points contained within 0.95th interval for the Hotelling; back to my previous comment, I thought this would be best plotted and IO have added a plot. Thanks for sharing with me how to find `qf`, I found the python alternative and it helped me make the plot. However, is the plot right in containing all values whereby T is significant?]

Comment: The plot for a $1-\alpha$ confidence region should contain values for $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ that you would NOT reject the null for in the test at level $\alpha$. So no, it does not contain "significant" values, quite the opposite.

Comment: @Glen_b question, how do I interpret `np.transpose(circle).dot(np.linalg.cholesky(sigma) * ed)` in the code above? Parts of it was taken online, especially this line, therefore how should I think about it?

Comment: Sorry the question is now quite far from where it started. It's no longer one I'm likely to seek to answer at the moment.  Make sure any questions you have now are clearly stated in your post.